# I am a beginner in python, can someone please explain me this piece of code in detail?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

```
marks = [95, 98, 97]

i = 0
while i < len(marks):
    print(marks[i])
    i = i + 1
```

I want to understand this print(marks[i]) and i = i + 1, what is its use here and why can it not be written before print function?

I am learning about while loop in list data type and I am not able to understand this code.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: The first element or item of `marks` is picked out using the index `[0]`. If you add 1 to `i` before print, the code will miss out `95`

Comment: The first print command is `print(marks[0]` and prints the value 95. If i = i +1 would have been written before the print command the print statement would be `print(marks[1]` and would therefore print the value 98. And you would get a problem with the last print command because the index would be 3 where 2 is the maximal possible index value.

Comment: you might get a satisfactory explanation from a step-through in [python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=marks%20%3D%20%5B95,%2098,%2097%5D%0A%0Ai%20%3D%200%0Awhile%20i%20%3C%20len%28marks%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28marks%5Bi%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20i%20%3D%20i%20%2B%201&cumulative=false&curInstr=12&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty basic question and there a numerous tutorials out there. That said, IRON MAN is obviously new here. Give him time to learn how things are handled here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create an array with the numbers 95, 98, 97
# remember that arrays are 0 indexed
# marks[0] is 95
# marks[1] is 98
# marks[2] is 97
marks = [95, 98, 97]

# set the variable i to 0
i = 0
# len(marks) returns the length of the array (3) so while i is less than 3
# as we are using less i will be 0, 1, 2. When i is 3 it's no longer less then 3 and the loop will end.
while i < len(marks):
    print(marks[i])
    # add one to i 1 becomes 2 etc (iterate)
    # if you do this before print you would look at marks[1] during first iteration rather than marks[0]
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to loop over a list is simply

```
for item in marks:
    print(item)
```

There are situations where you want to keep track of where you hre in the list, though then, maybe use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(marks, 1):
    print("item at position", idx, "is", item)
```

In lower-level languages, you are forced to always keep track of the index, as subscripting is the only way to access an individual array or list member. Even then, the Python idiom of choice would be `range(len(...))`:

```
for i in range(len(marks)):
    print(marks[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

`marks` is a `list`, that is, an object that contains a number of other objects. Three integers (numbers) in this case.

`print` outputs something to the console.

`while` defines a loop with a condition. In this case the condition is that the counter variable `i` remains `less than` the length (`len`) of the list `marks`.

`marks[i]` means, get the object with the index `i` from the list `marks`. Indexes of lists start at 0.

`i = i + 1` increments `i` by 1. It takes the current value of `i`, adds 1 to it and writes the result back to `i` (the `=` sign).

So, to sum it up, this piece of code just iterates (runs through) the list `marks` and prints out every item in the list to the console.

Answer (score 1):

So here `marks` is a list.

`i` is intiated with value `0`

Then we start a loop which has to run while `i < len(marks)`. Here marks has 3 elements therefore `len(marks) = 3`.

As `i` is `0` which is less than `3` the loop runs. We print `marks[i]` which means the element in marks at position `i` => `marks[0]` which is `95`.

Then we add `1` to `i`, i.e. `i = i+1` => `0 = 0+1` => `i = 1`

Now `i` i.e. `1` is still less than `len(marks)` so the loop runs again to print `marks[1]` which is `98` and so on.....

Answer (score 1):

We create a Python list of three integers:

```
marks = [95, 98, 97]
```

declare a counter named i and define it to 0

```
i = 0
```

Then using a while loop, we check if the condition i.e. i < len(marks) is evaluated to true.

And if it is true that the i counter is less than the length of the list, the body of the while loop is executed.

The body 'i = i + 1' says that each time the condition is true , we add 1 to i. So, i is incremented each time when the condition is true.

```
while i < len(marks):
    print(marks[i]) //prints the element each time at that i index 
    i = i + 1
```

When the condition is evaluated to false i.e. the condition is no more true, the loop terminates and so does the body of the loop.

So in our case, the program prints the whole content of the list using a while loop and i counter that increases by comparing itself to the actual length of the list i.e. len(marks).

Answer (score 0):

```
marks = [95, 98, 97]

i = 0
while i < len(marks):
    print(marks[i])
    i = i + 1
```

In this code, a list `marks` has been declared and initialised. This list contains 3 elements.
Next, there is a variable `i`initialized to `0`.

And next there is a `while` loop. With the `while` loop we can execute a set of statements as long as a condition is true. Here, the condition is `i < len(marks)`. And we know that `i` is initialized to `0`. So, as long as `i` is less than the size of the `marks` list, the body of `while` loop will be executed. In the body of the while loop, there are 2 statements. `print(marks[i])` prints the ith element of the marks list.`i = i+1` increments the `i` value by 1 so that next element of the list `marks` can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. So the '0' which is the value of 'i', here is considered as index number by this specific program, right?

Comment: Yes, the value of 'i' is used as an index.